# Can CPU / memory influence restore performance

Tags: sql-server, restore

I want to restore a database and it takes minutes.

I am using a virtual machine with 4 CPUs and 16GB of memory and I want to know if there is any relation between the CPU/Memory to the restore DB process?

For example: if I increase CPUs to 16 and memory to 48GB, should it be faster?

Comment: Generally, cpu and memory will not make it go faster. More bandwidth or faster response times at the disk layer will but cpu and memory are only minimally required*. [*] unless you're hitting high kernel times due to fast disk such as AFAs or internal NVMe.

Comment: Are you using a virtual machine? If the storage is based on thin provisioning or dynamic disks, IO performance might be poor. Check that you use IFI and that transaction log is of reasonable size.

Comment: @vonPryz Yes virtual machine but the disk is pretty strong with 20,000 provisioning IOPS.

Comment: How big is the backup file? How big is the database when it gets restored? When you run the restore, what does the output tell you the I/O speed was? How do you know you're getting the I/O performance that has allegedly been "provisioned"?

Comment: CPU would matter if your backup were compressed.

Comment: As @vonPryz asked - do you have Instant File Initialization enabled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can CPU / memory influence restore performance

Restoring involves bringing data pages into memory so yes memory can be a factor but cannot be a show stopper. Things which really can affect backup performance are the drives on which data file and backup resides and the network connectivity. Ofcourse you will see faster restore speed on SSD's as compared to SATA disks.

Read [How SQL Server backup and restore operation works](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/psssql/2008/02/06/how-it-works-how-does-sql-server-backup-and-restore-select-transfer-sizes/). This will let you know how memory is internally used while backup and restore operation

If you read this [BOL document](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190954%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) it shows how you can improve performance of SQL Server restore process